# How to get user information after REST authentication on client side?

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, rest, spring-rest

I have Spring REST backend and Angular frontend.

Authentication is performed using a POST request to "/login" URL with username and password inside request JSON body (I use form based authentication).
REST backend replies with OK code. Everything is fine and I can perform other requests from frontend that requires authentication.

But frontend need to know what is the role of authenticated user so that it can display a proper view/rote for it. And where can we get this role on a frontend? The only response we got from authentication was OK and that is fine for REST.

We can get user information by performing GET request to "/users/[user_id]". But we don't have user id, just user name.

So the question is - **what is a correct way for REST to get role (or other user information) from frontend having just user name?**

As a workaround I can create new request on a backend that takes user name instead of id, or I can add user id to authentication response. But I'm not really sure that is a correct way from REST perspective.

Comment: If your backend requires to pass a user ID to get the current user information, but doesn't allow getting the user ID, then the backend has a serious design problem. You seem to be able to send a request requiring authentication. That means that the backend is able to identify who you are (probably thanks to a cookie). If that's true, you don't need to pass anything as parameter, since it's implicitly passed in the cookie. You can just have a /current-user resource.

Comment: Both backend and frontend are under development by me. What is a correct way for backend to provide user information following REST?

Comment: I just told you. Assuming the backend has an implicit way of identifying the requests (using a cookie, for example), you can just provide a /current-user, or a /me or whatever you want to name it, resource. See https://developer.github.com/v3/users/#get-the-authenticated-user for example.

Comment: Will that be fine from REST perspective? I'm not sure what does "POST /current-user" or "DELETE /current-user" mean.

Comment: Why do you think every resource must support a delete or a post action?

Comment: I'm really bad at REST but my understanding is that you should think about DELETE, POST etc. operations when you add a resource to REST service.
Thanks for the link. It seems correct design of backend service is to have "users/:username" endpoint instead of "users/:userid"?

Comment: If the username is the unique identifier of the user, yes. Your understanding is wrong. If a resource is read-only, then it makes no sense to provide a DELETE and a POST method for that resource. Have you noticed that the github api uses just /user to get the authenticated user?

Comment: Great. Thank you.

Comment: @JBNizet could you please move you suggestions regarding endpoint design (i.e. having "/users/:name" instead of "/users/:id") to a separate answer so that I can mark it as the answer? Otherwise I will do that myself but that may complicate an understanding for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussing the issue with @JBNizet in comments I decided to change REST endpoint from "/users/:user_id" to "/users/:user_name".

Answer (score 0):

You can not override HTTP Methods.So,if you are planning to write GET call with diffrent query parameters with the same path,then it is not allowed.You need to write two GET paths.

e.g.

GET /users/userid/{id}
GET /users/username/{name}

And in the second call,you can add desired logic for getting role in the second one.

Comment: But from REST perspective I'm not sure that this is correct. What does "DELETE /users/username" mean?

Comment: If you don't want to allow DELETE,then don't write implementation for DELETE call.This is perfectly acceptable according to REST standard.

Answer (score 0):

There are two way's of doing it.

1) After successful authentication from the server, do one more `$http` call to the server with username from which you can fetch details from a server logic that fetches and store that result in the `$rootScope`.This info will be available through out the app.

2) When you are authenticating the user, if the user is valid then fetch his details and store those in an object.

Now in your server logic while returning response you can do like below

```
response.setHeaders("User",userDetilsObj);
```

**NOTE**: response is a HttpServletResponse object.

After the request is completed as you said we will get a status OK response that is 200. To access the user details at JS side follow below code

```
if(response.status == '200/OK'){
   $rootScope.user = response.getHeaders().User;//In this object all the user details set at server side are available now..
}
```

Hope this gives you some light on how to achieve your desired results.

Comment: Thank you. These 2 ways look very similar to workarounds I mentioned in the question. And the question is about another thing. JB Nizet pointed that replacing "/users/:id" with "/users/:name" endpoint is ok from design point of view so that answers my question.

Comment: yes agreed, but you have asked which is better way of doing it so I would suggest go for the first approach which is cleaner and maintainable.

Comment: Using "/users/:name"  is not a cleaner approach because ID is something which will remain forever constant name can be changed or it can case sensitive which again a conversion is required what if you have more users with same name ? How will you decide which one has logged in ?

Comment: Just read my question and our discussion with @JBNizet and that will safe your time from repeating this question and JBNizet words.

Answer (score 0):

Get the user information from server at the the time when you authenticates the user.Pass the user details on successful user authentication.